# A página volta pro topo a cada elemento <a> pressionado, como impedir?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com problemas em uma parte do código onde cada vez que pressiono qualquer botão, a página vai pro topo.

Tenho só alguns números, mas no futuro serão diversos números (elementos âncora) que vou selecionar para enviar um formulário. Foi por esse motivo que eu populei a página com um lixo escrito só para fazer corpo e ficar fácil de perceber que ela ta voltando pro topo sem necessidade.

Código:

```js
console.log('teste');

// var UIController = (function() {
//     return {
//       getinput: function() {
//         todosItens = document.querySelector('.btn_reservas').toggleAttribute;
//       }
//     };
  
//   })();
var controller = (function() {

  var ctrlAddItem = function(event) {
  console.log('It worked, pressed id  = ' + event.target.id);
  event.target.classList.toggle("active");
  }
  
  document.querySelectorAll(".btn_reservas").forEach(function () {
      this.addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem);
    });
  
  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
          ctrlAddItem();
      }
  });
  
  })();
```

```css
.lista ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.lista ul li a {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #bfc0bf;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 75px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgb(85, 161, 108);
  border-color: #212529;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.lista ul li a:hover {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font: bolder;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}

.lista ul li a.active {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-6">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/antigo.css"> 

    <title> Pagina de sorteio </title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sorteio.html">Sorteio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sobrenos.html">Sobre Nos</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <hr>
    <h1>VAMOS</h1>
    <hr>
    <h1>ABAIXAR</h1>
    <hr>
    <h1>ESSA PAGINA</h1>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <h1>VAMOS</h1>
    <hr>
    <h1>ABAIXAR</h1>
    <hr>
    <h1>ESSA PAGINA</h1>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <h1>VAMOS</h1>
    <hr>
    <h1>ABAIXAR</h1>
    <hr>
    <h1>ESSA PAGINA</h1>
    <hr>

    <div class="lista_sorteio">
    <h1>O GRANDE SORTEIo</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="legenda">
        <ul>
            <li>
              <b class="disponivel">Disponiveis</b>  
            </li>
            <li>
                <b class="reservados">Reservados</b>
            </li>
            <li>
                <b class="pagos">Pagos</b>
            </li>
            <li>
                <b class ="enviar">Enviar Comprovante</b>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="lista">
        <ul >
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="00" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">01</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="01" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">02</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="02" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">03</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="03" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">04</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="04" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">05</a>        
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
<div><hr>
<hr>
<hr></div>        
    <script src ="apps/numeros.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A tag `a` é usada para links, no seu caso use `span` ao invés de `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando vc tem um elemento `<a>` com o atributo `href` igual a `#`, significa que ele vai jogar a página p/ o topo, sempre q esse elemento for clicado.

E por que isso acontece?

Veja bem, o elemento `<a>` (de âncora) quando usado para conectar elementos da mesma página da forma como vc está usando (com o valor de `href="#"`), indica que o navegador deve procurar o elemento com o `id` indicado, como vc não passou absolutamente nenhum valor depois do `#`, o navegador simplesmente vai rolar para o topo da página.

Mas vamos supor que vc tenha um elemento com atributo `id="aqui"` em qualquer lugar da página e vc tenha uma âncora com `href="#aqui"`, significa que quando o usuário clicar nesta âncora, o navegador vai fazer a rolagem diretamente para o elemento com `id="aqui` ficar logo ao topo da janela.

Quando vc usa

Comment: Matou a charada, só precisei colocar  o #id, pra minha página parar de voltar ao topo, muitíssimo obrigado.